# Issues with In-app-billing on React Native

Tags: reactjs, in-app-billing, react-native

I'm implementing In-app-billing on my React Native project using this.
https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing

This is the code I'm using.

```
InAppBilling.open()
.then(() => InAppBilling.purchase('android.test.purchased'))
.then((details) => {
  console.log("You purchased: ", details)
  return InAppBilling.close()
});
```

and I got this error.

[image]

Can anyone help me with the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an emulator?

Comment: Yes, but also tried on real device, and it still happens.

Comment: Make sure you have installed library correctly. If InAppBillingBridge is undefined, NativeModules may not be built correctly. Do not forget to import and include package in MainApplication.java. 

// add package here
new InAppBillingBridgePackage()

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed the github issues and found that he closed the issue without the correct solution.

Comment: Oh I just posted one of his answers - did you try linking?

Comment: Sure, I did it, it was the installation process, let me try again.

Comment: It says this rnpm-install info Android module react-native-billing is already linked, is there any way to reinstall it?

Comment: You might need to reset watchman and the packager. Try the command I posted in the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing/issues/45):

> "Easiest way is to run `react-native link` `react-native-billing`
>   after `npm install --save react-native-billing`. That will add the
>   native build config for you. The link command will be adding the
>   native config, and you do not have to follow the manual installation.
>
> But your build.gradle should not contain com.anjlab.android.iab.v3
>   since that is added by this module in another file. Yours should
>   instead have something like compile project(':react-native-billing')."

After making a change like this I always run these in the terminal to reset everything and then refresh the app afterwards:

`watchman watch-del-all`

`node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --reset-cache`

Comment: The issue is still remaining.

Comment: The next thing I'd do is check your `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`

Comment: Hmm It's always tricky adding new libraries to RN - especially android. I always seem to find the solution some how in the way I need to either link, configure or reset things.

Comment: Thanks, let me try

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've succeeded with this is by re-ejecting the app, rebuilding node modules and pods, and linking all libraries at the very end with `react-native link`.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to uninstall and install app after install the library?
If you just reload the app with the node files will not work. You need to unsinstall and reinstall the app to get the Inappbilling in your application.